# Ajax added Header to post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, header, access-token

I am using ajax post request to create users it work fine until  the header added to the ajax request .

after header added to that ajax post  request then the data value changed from hash to string

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/user/create',
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Token', 'xxxxxxxxx');
  },
  data: {
    name: 'xxxx',
    email: 'sample@sample.com'
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

can any one help.

thanks in advance

Comment: could you post that hash code and string which your referring to  ?

Comment: normal hash value  {name: 'xxxx',email: 'sample@sample.com'} after adding header it changes into "name: 'xxxx',email: 'sample@sample.com"

Comment: looks like the json data is turned into a string, so you can just parse your string at the other end. in js you can parse like this `JSON.parse(string)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by using **processData: false** in your ajax call.

For I.E.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/user/create',
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Token', 'xxxxxxxxx');
  },
  data: {
    name: 'xxxx',
    email: 'sample@sample.com'
  },
  processData: false,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

This may help you